# API versions for android BLE

Tags: android, eclipse, api, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was wondering if there was a way to develop a BLE app for API's 18+ till the latest API. I know that some commands (startLeScan, stopLeScan) were deprecated in API 21 causing the minimum API to be prompted to get set at 21. If a 'build.version' command is incorporated for certain commands to only function for certain API's, the old command is still striked through and prompted to be changed to the new commands which then prompts the change of the min API level. Has anyone found a way to write an app that functions for all API's that support BLE using eclipse or Android Studio?

Thanks!

Comment: I use BLE for beacons detection using the API 22 and i don't have this problem. It works fine with my Galaxy S3 under Kitkat

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. Something like this should work:

```
//for Lollipop or newer
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(mNewLeScanCallback)
}//for 4.3 and 4.4
else{
    mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mOldLEScanCallback);
}
```

Of course you will also have to implement the two different callbacks. Add

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
```

Before the methods that use the new APIs so that you don't get the warnings.